# How to distinguish ASP.NET Core Attribute-based Routing for Overloading Functions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api-routing, asp.net-core-routing

Is it possible to distinguish API routing for overloading functions?

For example I have the following functions:

```
[HttpGet("filter")]
public JsonResult GetCity (int id) { ... }

[HttpGet("filter")]
public JsonResult GetCity (int id, string name) { ... }
```

I want to call the first function if the user call it through

```
http://localhost:5000/api/cities/filter?id=1
```

and call the second using

```
http://localhost:5000/api/cities/filter?id=1&name=NewYork
```

Can we achieve it with the suggested format?

I mean with `?paramter=value` not with forward slashes like `http://localhost:5000/api/cities/filter/1/NewYork`

Comment: Action methods don't support overloads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have two actions like that, no. When calling an action, it only looks to see that the needed parameters are provided, and ignores any provided parameters that the action does not need.

So calling `id=1&name=NewYork` will match to `GetCity (int id)` because all it needs is `id`, and `name` gets ignored.

But then of course it matches to `GetCity (int id, string name)` as well.

What you can do is keep only one action and call another method if the `name` is not provided, like this:

```
    [HttpGet("filter")]
    public JsonResult GetCity(int id, string name) {
        if (name == null) return GetCityWithId(id);
        ...
    }

    private JsonResult GetCityWithId(int id) {
        ...
    }
```